# Difference in time complexity of toString and join of array

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference in time complexity between `[1,2,3].toString()` and `[1,2,3].join()` . As I understand time complexity of `join` function is `O(n)` . What is the time complexity of `.toString()` method ?

Comment: `Array.prototype.toString` calls `Array.prototype.join` with `','`. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) [Spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.tostring)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both have the same time complexity. `Array.prototype.toString` calls `Array.prototype.join` without argument. `','` is the default separator.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) [Spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.tostring)

Answer (score 1):

toString() has the same time complexity of join(), the difference is that with join() is possible to choose the separator.

array.join([separator]);